# Is it possible to get a core dump of a running process and its symbol table?

Tags: debugging, coredump

Is it possible to get gdb or use some other tools to create a core dump of a running process and it's symbol table?  It would be great if there's a way to do this without terminating the process.

If this is possible, what commands would you use?  (I'm trying to do this on a Linux box)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
$ gdb --pid=26426
(gdb) gcore
Saved corefile core.26426
(gdb) detach
```

Comment: You don't need to set ulimit -c unlimited as gdb doesn't respect it (gdb should always give you the entire core file). You can also do this using the command `gcore pid` from the cli without running gdb.

Answer (score 91):

Or run `gcore $(pidof processname)`.

This has the benefit (over running gdb and issuing commands to the CLI) that you attach and detach in the shortest possible time.

Answer (score 2):

You can used `generate-core-file` command in gdb to generate core dump of running process.