# How can I generate a core dump in Python?

Tags: python, elf, coredump, gcore

I'm trying to generate a core dump of a running process (without killing it, just like the gdb command `gcore`) using python.

The objective is, from a given pid, to generate a gdb-readable core dump.

Core dumps are in the ELF format and I've not been able to find python libraries to create ELF files from scratch (the `elffile` library is outdated and other libraries only allow reading ELF files).
And even if it existed, I am not able to find precise explanations on what portions of memory are written in the core dump file and what portions aren't.

My question is, can I generate core dumps through python easily, or do I need to re-write the `gcore` command in python entirely (meaning writing the ELF file manually)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get a core dump of a running process and its symbol table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160/is-it-possible-to-get-a-core-dump-of-a-running-process-and-its-symbol-table)

Comment: Not really, because I'm trying to get python to create the core dump, as the host running the script may not have the ```gcore``` command installed

Comment: send a SIGABRT signal to call the python3 default handler which creates a core dump by default...